# Try to connect IBM MQ with PHP MQ 9.2

Tags: php, ibm-mq

We are using linux server CENTOS 7 but virtual. We install to /var/mqm **(9.2-IBM-MQC-linux)** to our server. we install /**mqseries-0.15.0** with /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/phpize to our server. we try to connect with IBM MQ with php code

```
<?php

$mq_host_ip='****(1414)';
$queue_name = '****';
$mq_server = '****';
$mqcno = array(
'Version' => MQSERIES_MQCNO_VERSION_2,
'Options' => MQSERIES_MQCNO_STANDARD_BINDING,
'MQCD' => array(
"ChannelName" => "*****",
'ConnectionName' => $mq_host_ip,
'TransportType' => MQSERIES_MQXPT_TCP
)
);
// Connect to the MQ server
mqseries_connx($mq_server,$mqcno,$conn,$comp_code,$reason);
if ($comp_code !== MQSERIES_MQCC_OK) {
    echo 'Cannot open connection to server: ' . $comp_code ."--".$reason."--". mqseries_strerror($reason);
}else{
     echo 'Connection good!';
}

?>
```

we get the error this
**Cannot open connection to server: 2--2035--Not authorized for access.**
.This is the our folder **/home/trialwebsite/public_html**.

Best Regards.
Murat ÖZKAN

Answer (score 0):

The queue manager error log will usually tell you what specifically is wrong with the authentication/authorisation for a client program. The userid associated with the channel does not have appropriate rights or cannot be authenticated.

But one problem you might have with PHP is that it looks like the PECL-published PHP MQ library has not been maintained for a number of years and does not recognise the MQCSP structure needed to set the userid/password that the queue manager might be expecting. There is an un-merged PR opened at https://github.com/php/pecl-networking-mqseries/pull/5 which claims to add the MQCSP support so you might be able to do a git clone and use that branch as an alternative source of the interface.

Comment: Thank you sir. im trying but, know i get Reason:2381 Text:On an MQCONN or MQCONNX call, the location of the key repository is either not specified, not valid, or results in an error when used to access the key repository.   this error. So im not good i know but i have big problem with IBM MQ. Thank you again for your help. BEST REGARDS

Comment: @Muratözkan I don't see anything in your question describing where you have specified the key repository. Can you update your question to show those details so that we can assist further?